# What's wrong with my code: wrong value output when I try to calculate Euler's number, e, in C?

Tags: c, eulers-number

I'm trying to approximate Euler's number in C using a loop that terminates when the difference between two successive values of e is less than 0.0000001. The value I get is 2.99.. I tried setting it up so that with each iteration, e will be compared with the previous value of itself (held in e1) and if the difference is greater than 0.0000001 it will add another term 1/(n!). What's the issue? I'm new to programming so any advice/critiquing is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float e1 = 0, e2 = 1;
    int n = 1, nfact; 

    while ((e2 - e1) > 0.0000001)         
    {
        e1 = e2;   
        nfact = 1;
        for (int count = 1; count < n; count++)     
        {
            nfact = n * count;
        }
        n = n + 1;
        e2 = e1 + (1.0 / nfact);
    }   

    printf("Approximated value of e = %f", e2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You `for` loop will be not executed since `count` is 1 and it's not less then `n` which is also 1!

Comment: It *might* be because `nfact` overflows. Try using a floating-point type for this variable.

Comment: @Rizier123: `n = n + 1;`

Comment: @Rizier123 Not true. `n` is incremented.

Comment: @deviantfan oh your right! Thanks overlooked that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nfact = 1;
for (int count = 1; count < n; count++)     
{
    nfact = n * count;
}
```

won´t calculate `n!`.
nfact gets a completely new value every iteration.
Surely you mean

```
nfact = 1;
for (int count = 2; count <= n; count++)     
{
    nfact *= count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you calculate the factorial of a number:

```
for (int count = 1; count < n; count++)     
{
   nfact = n * count;
}
```

Notice that you always assign to `nfact` on each iteration to the value of `n*count`, obliterating the previous value of `nfact`. This piece of code is equivalent to:

```
nfact = n*(n-1);
```

Since that's the last value of `count`.

I think you wanted this instead:

```
nfact = n;
for (int count = n-1; count > 0; count--)     
{
    nfact = nfact * count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for
estimates the value of the mathematical constant e by using the formula:
e = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ....

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int n = 0;          /* loop counter for accuracy */
    int accuracy = 10;  /* current n factorial */
    int fact = 1;       /* degree of accuracy */
    double e = 0;       /* current estimated value of e */
```

/* loop until degree of accuracy */

```
    while (n <= accuracy) {

        if (n == 0) {
            fact *= 1;
        } else {
            fact *= n;
        }
        e += 1.0 / fact;

        ++n;

    }

    printf("e is %f", e);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain *what*  you are doing here and not post plain code?